# Are all additionlike operations on $\mathbb{R}$ of this form?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, binary-operations, magma

Suppose we're given real numbers $x,x',y,y' \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$|x-x'| \leq a, \qquad |y-y'| \leq b.$$

Then $$|(x+y)-(x'+y')| = |(x-x')+(y-y')| \leq |x-x'| + |y-y'| \leq a+b$$

This tells us that if we know a real number $x$ to a precision of $a$, and if we know $y$ to a precision of $b$, then we know $x+y$ to a precision of $a+b$.

Interestingly, the above argument only needs the following two properties of addition:

**Axiom 0.** $(x\star y) - (x' \star y') = (x-x') \star (y-y')$

**Axiom 1.** $|x \star y| \leq |x| \star |y|$.

Call a binary operation on $\mathbb{R}$ *additionlike* iff it satisfies these two axioms.

It's easy to see that the operation defined by $x \star y = k(x+y)$ is additionlike, for all $k \geq 0$.

> **Question.**  Are all additionlike operations on $\mathbb{R}$ of this form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexis Olson showed in his answer that the maps $x \star y = a x + b y$ with $a,b \geq 0$ satisfy axioms $0$ and $1$. I will show that these are the only ones.

Denote by $m$ the map $m : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $m(x,y)= x\star y$. Then Axiom $0$ is actually equivalent to the additivity of $m$.

Indeed, writing $z=(x,y)$ and $z' = (x', y')$, Axiom $0$ gives $m(z-z') = m(z)-m(z')$ for all $z, z'$. In particular, $m(0) = m(0 - 0 ) = m(0) - m(0)=0$. This in turn gives $m(- z) = m(0 -z) = m(0) - m(z) = - m(z)$ for all $z$. Thus we conclude that for any $z, z'$ we have $m(z+z') = m(z - (-z')) = m(z) - m(-z')) = m(z) + m(z')$. Conversely, additivity clearly implies Axiom $0$.

Since $m$ is additive, we have $m(x,y) = m(x,0) + m(0,y)$ for all $x,y$. Thus $m$ can be written as a sum $m(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)$, where $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are both additive.

To prove the claim, we must show that $f$ and $g$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linear. Assuming the axiom of choice, there exist additive maps on $\mathbb{R}$ that are not $\mathbb{R}$-linear, but they are highly pathological (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492/258909) for a review of additive maps on $\mathbb{R}$). I claim that Axiom $1$ prevents this from happening.

Indeed, an additive map on $\mathbb{R}$ that is *not* $\mathbb{R}$-linear has the property that its graph is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (a proof is given on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)). However, an immediate consequence of Axiom $1$ is that if $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$ then $| x \star y | \leq x \star y$, and in particular $x \star y \geq 0$. Thus $f$ and $g$ both map $[0,\infty)$ to itself. Therefore, their graphs cannot be dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so they must be linear. We conclude that $m$ is given by $m(x,y) = a x + b y$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, and since $f$ and $g$ map $[0,\infty)$ to itself we must have $a,b \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Any linear map with non-negative coefficients will satisfy these axioms.

If $x \star y = ax + by$ with $a,b \ge 0$, then

\begin{eqnarray}
(x\star y) - (x' \star y') &=& (ax + by) - (ax' - by')\\
&=& a(x-x') - b(y-y')\\
&=& (x-x') \star (y-y')
\end{eqnarray}

and

$$|x \star y| = |ax + by| \le |ax| + |by| = a|x| + b|y| = |x|\star|y|.$$

Your characterization is the special case where $a = b = k$.

Comment: You mean "linear", not "bilinear".

Comment: @EricWofsey Why?

Comment: A bilinear form is something like $xy$, not $x+y$.  It's a linear map in each variable when you fix a value of the other variable.

Comment: Is it necessary that $ x\star y =ax+by$ for some constants $a,b$?